# Detecting key presses in wxStyledTextCtrl and setting style for selected text

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm using wxWidgets to create a simple notepad style application.  I've created a `wxStyledTextCtrl` box using:

```cpp
class MyRichText : public wxStyledTextCtrl
{
public:
    MyRichText(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, long style = 0)
        : wxStyledTextCtrl(parent, id, pos, size, style)
    {
    }
};
//...and in my mcMain: 
long style = wxHSCROLL | wxTE_MULTILINE;
m_NoteContent = new MyRichText(scrolledWindow, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(770, 620), style);
```

Now I'm trying to detect key presses by the user within that text box, specifically things like Ctrl+B which would then apply the bold style to the selected text.  But I'm not sure how to do it.

Bind and Macros don't seem to be supported.

EDIT:
Nevermind.  I was able to fix it.  I was making it overly complicated (which happens as I'm only coding for 2 weeks and don't always see the simple solutions.)
FIX:

c++

```
class MyRichText : public wxStyledTextCtrl
{
public:
    MyRichText(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, long style = 0)

    : wxStyledTextCtrl(parent, id, pos, size, style) {}

void OnNoteContentKeyDown(wxKeyEvent& event)
{
    int keyCode = event.GetKeyCode();

    // Check if the control key is pressed and the key is 's' (or 'S')
    if (event.GetModifiers() == wxMOD_CONTROL && (keyCode == 'S' || keyCode == 's')) {
        // E.G Save the document...just messagebox for now
        wxMessageBox("Ctrl+S pressed. Saved the document.");
    }
    else {
        event.Skip(); // Allow normal key event processing
    }
}

wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
```

};
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyRichText, wxStyledTextCtrl)
EVT_KEY_DOWN(MyRichText::OnNoteContentKeyDown)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

...and then declare it in the header with:

```
void OnNoteContentKeyDown(wxStyledTextEvent& event);
```

Comment: did you try to run the stc sample?

Comment: Where are you handling events or messages?  A keypress is sent as an event in wxWidgets.  Research "wxWidgets events keyboard".